# Missing User-agent directive! Found Allow - what does this mean?

Tags: user-agent, robots.txt

I ran my site through http://www.frobee.com/robots-txt-check and it came back with a few errors.

Here is my robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/

# Allowable Index
Allow: /*?p=
Allow: /blog/
Allow: /catalog/seo_sitemap/category/
Allow: /catalogsearch/result/

# Directories
Disallow: /404/
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /downloader/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /js/
Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /magento/
Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /skin/
Disallow: /stats/
Disallow: /var/

# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /index.php/
Disallow: /catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /control/
Disallow: /contacts/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /customize/
Disallow: /newsletter/
Disallow: /poll/
Disallow: /review/
Disallow: /sendfriend/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /wishlist/

 # Files
 Disallow: /cron.php
 Disallow: /cron.sh
 Disallow: /error_log
 Disallow: /install.php
 Disallow: /LICENSE.html
 Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
 Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
 Disallow: /STATUS.txt

 # Paths (no clean URLs)
 Disallow: /*.js$
 Disallow: /*.css$
 Disallow: /*.php$
 Disallow: /*?p=*&
 Disallow: /*?SID=
 Disallow: /*?*
```

The errors I get are 'Missing User-agent directive! Found Allow' and 'Missing User-agent directive! Found Disallow'. I'm not sure why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In robots.txt empty lines are used to separate multiple directives. Just remove or comment the empty lines and you should be fine.

Comment: You could comment the empty lines out (`#`) if you like to keep the visual separation.